# htaccess setting request from admin folder index to load from base folder sub directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I wanted to call files from **bacchus/public/img/logo.png** from **bacchus/admin/index.php** but I am not able to do so since the directory requires me to jump back to the base page.  
Two things to note here, I have edited htaccess that change the request of **img/logo.png** to **public/img/logo.png** so it would display the image without needing to add **public/**, and the second thing is if you put this file **admin/index.php** in **bacchus** it works.

admin/index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Bacchus</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="<?php echo 'img/logo.png';?>" alt="" srcset="">
</body>
</html>
```

.htaccess

```
#get image, code from public folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\/(js|img|css)\/.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(?=admin)admin
RewriteRule ^((js|img|css)\/.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (?=admin)admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^((js|img|css)\/.*)$ /bacchus/public/$1
#prevent cache storing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(js|css)
RewriteRule ^/$ - [ENV=AD:true,L]
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" env=AD
Header set Pragma "no-cache" env=AD
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT" env=AD
```

Comment: Either ``<?php echo '/img/logo.png';?>`` or ``<?php echo '../img/logo.png';?>``.

Comment: Nevermind, I found a solution which is to add base href of "/bacchus/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add base href="/bacchus/" to index.php